# Android WebView reporting incorrect content height

Tags: android, scroll, android-webview

I'm working on an `Android` app that is supposed to load a web page, and if the content height is larger than the view height, scroll the content.

The issue is that on several pages, it seems `WebView.getContentHeight()` returns the exact height of the view, even when I can manually scroll down. This means I don't have the correct values for an animator, and scrolling doesn't work correctly.

Currently, to test the issue, I've set a scroll change listener to log a message when the `WebView` is scrolled to the end.

```
        webView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(View view, int i, int i1, int i2, int i3) {
            Log.d(TAG, String.format("scrollX: %d, scrollY: %d, oldScrollX: %d, oldScrollY: %d", i, i1, i2, i3));
            int height = (int) Math.floor(webView.getContentHeight() * webView.getScaleY());
            if (webView.getScrollY() + webView.getHeight() >= height && progress > 99)
                Log.d(TAG, "Reached bottom: " + height);
        }
    });
```

The logs show the scaled content height being 1586, and the web view height being 1586. However, I can manually scroll the page down, and I get this log output:

```
WebPageView: scrollX: 0, scrollY: 1960, oldScrollX: 0, oldScrollY: 1774
WebPageView: Reached bottom: 1773
WebPageView: scrollX: 0, scrollY: 1959, oldScrollX: 0, oldScrollY: 1960
WebPageView: Reached bottom: 1773
```

To me, this clearly shows that the content height is being misreported, as:

```
WebView.getScrollY() + WebView.getHeight() > WebView.getContentHeight() * WebView.getScaleY()
```

I've set a `WebChromeClient` as well, and overloaded `onProgressChanged()`, and I know that when the content height is being retrieved, the page is finished loading.

What might be causing `WebView` to misreport the content height as one page, when it's really much larger?

EDIT: I've run the app on Android 6.0, 7.0, and 7.1. The minSdkVersion in build.gradle is 23, and the targetSdkVersion is 25. The WebView version is 44.0.2403.119.

Comment: Please specify the version of Android OS where you have observed this issue.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Having same issue.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: As pointed out in a comment, `computeVerticalScrollRange()` is a protected method, so you'll have to subclass WebView to make this approach work. This can be accomplished either through putting the listener in the subclass or creating an accessor method to return the value of the protected method.**

---

Instead of using `getContentHeight()`, try using `computeVerticalScrollRange()`.

Scrolling values are expressed as arbitrary units, but they're consistent across all of the different methods that return or use a scrolling value. So while the content height might be in pixels, the scrolling units are not. You'd want to update your code as such to detect scrolling to the bottom accurately.

In Java:

```
webView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollChange(View view, int i, int i1, int i2, int i3) {
        int maxScrollRange = computeVerticalScrollRange();
        if (webView.getScrollY() + webView.getMeasuredHeight() >= maxScrollRange) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Reached the bottom.");
        }
    }
});
```

Or in kotlin:

```
webView.setOnScrollChangeListener { _,_,_,_,_ ->
    val maxScrollRange = computeVerticalScrollRange()
    if(webView.scrollY + webView.measuredHeight >= maxScrollRange) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Reached the bottom.")
    }
}
```

Comment: This method is protected and can't be accessed.

Comment: @saltandpepper That's actually an excellent point. I just realized that I'm using it in a WebView subclass. I'll have to update my answer accordingly.